# How to use Moq to simulate exceptions thrown by the StackExchange.Redis library?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, stackexchange.redis

I'm working on a project where I would like to use the StackExchange.Redis library to connect to a Redis database. In addition, I'd like to use Moq for the mocking library in our unit tests, but I'm running into a roadblock that I need some help to resolve.

My specific issue, is that I have a command/response architecture and I'm trying to test a cache "wrapper" that checks if a command can be satisfied by the cache before doing the actual work to return the response. An important consideration is that cache failures should never stop a request from being handled, so I want to to mock out certain failures for the StackExchange.Redis *IDatabase* interface. However, I can't seem to figure out how to throw a RedisException from my mocked object. For example, I'd like to just use the following code, but it doesn't compile because there's no public constructor for the exceptions thrown by this library.

```
    Mock<IDatabase> _mockCache = new Mock<IDatabase>();

    // Simulate a connection exception to validate how the cache layer handles it
    //  THIS DOESN'T COMPILE THOUGH
    //
    _mockCache.Setup(cache => cache.StringGetAsync("a", CommandFlags.None)).Throws<RedisException>();
```

Is there a better way to mock up failures within the StackExchange.Redis library? I feel like I'm missing something obvious either with Moq or with how to test against this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create an instance of a class without running any constructor:

> Creates a new instance of the specified object type.
>
> Because the new instance of the object is initialized to zero and no constructors are run, the object might not represent a state that is regarded as valid by that object. The current method should only be used for deserialization when the user intends to immediately populate all fields. It does not create an uninitialized string, since creating an empty instance of an immutable type serves no purpose.

So your setup could look like this:

```
var e = (RedisException)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(RedisException)); 

Mock<IDatabase> _mockCache = new Mock<IDatabase>();
_mockCache.Setup(cache => cache.StringGetAsync("a", CommandFlags.None)).Throws(e);
```

It's a little hackish; since no constructors are run, you should not rely on a valid state of the `RedisException` instance.

Comment: That works for what I need. I wasn't aware of *FormatterServices*, so thank you!